# C# Simplifying an excel read program

Tags: c#

I'm grabbing the totals of each string that I created. Is there a way to simplify this by doing loops? I've tried a couple different methods but haven't had any luck. This code prints what I want too. But I know their is easier way to write it.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var fileExcel = @"C:test.xlsx";
            var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel);
            var xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            var xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Columns["A:I"];

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

// array for product names
            string[] productNames = { "TOTAL 1", "Total 2", "Total 3", "Total 4", "Total 5", "Total 6" };

// find productName from array to find totals
var foundProduct1 = xlRange.Find(productNames[0]);
            var rangeOne = foundProduct1.FindNext();
            var rangeTwo = rangeOne.FindNext();
            var foundProduct2 = xlRange.Find(productNames[1]);
            var rangeThree = foundProduct2.FindNext();
            var foundProduct3 = xlRange.Find(productNames[2]);
            var foundProduct4 = xlRange.Find(productNames[3]);
            var foundProduct5 = xlRange.Find(productNames[4]);
            var rangeFour = foundProduct5.FindNext();
            var foundProduct6 = xlRange.Find(productNames[5]);


            // find values of all totals

            var firstValue = xlApp.get_Range($"C{foundProduct1.Row}");
            var secondValue = xlApp.get_Range($"D{rangeOne.Row}");
            var thirdValue = xlApp.get_Range($"G{rangeTwo.Row}");
            var fourthValue = xlApp.get_Range($"C{foundProduct2.Row}");
            var fifthValue = xlApp.get_Range($"G{rangeThree.Row}");
            var sixthValue = xlApp.get_Range($"H{foundProduct3.Row}");
            var seventhValue = xlApp.get_Range($"D{foundProduct4.Row}");
            var eighthValue = xlApp.get_Range($"C{foundProduct5.Row}");
            var ninthValue = xlApp.get_Range($"D{rangeFour.Row}");
            var tenthValue = xlApp.get_Range($"D{foundProduct6.Row}");



            // Write out total values.
            Console.WriteLine("012100 - 20 - Totes: " + firstValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012100 - 42 - Bags: " + secondValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012100 - A-1 - Bags: " + thirdValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012110 - 20 - Totes: " + fourthValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012110 - A-1 - Bags: " + fifthValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012101 - 2Q - Bags: " + sixthValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012150 - 42 - Bags: " + seventhValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012180 - 20 - Totes: " + eighthValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012180 - 42 - Bags: " + ninthValue.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("012181 - 42 - Bags: " + tenthValue.Value);
```

[image: Excel Data]

Comment: please include `using` statements, and it would very useful if you also include an excel sample to know how values are arranged in the sheet.

Comment: @iSR5 There you go. Thanks

Comment: thanks, so you're only interested in the highlighted rows only?

Comment: Yeah my code works but I know there is more efficient way to code it. Maybe through a loop?

Answer (score 1):

you could make use of a class model to hold the values, and loop over the used range only. Check the first column cell in each iteration to match the text `Total x` where the `x` would be the number of given totals which would be incremented every time it match one. So, you start with `Total 1` and loop over the range, and whenever the check returns true, you add the values to the model, then increment the total counter by 1, and use the new number with the next iteration, and so on.

Here is an example :

Model :

```
 public class TotalModel
    {
        public int Tatoes20 { get; set; }
        public int Bags42 { get; set; }
        public int Bags2Q { get; set; }
        public int BagsA1 { get; set; }
        public int Tatoes14 { get; set; }
        public int Tatoes28 { get; set; }
        public int Bags2K { get; set; }
    }
```

now use it :

```
 const string totalTemplate = "TOTAL {0}";
 var xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Columns["A:I"];

    // only get the used rows and not the entire sheet rows.
    int rowCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;

    var model = new TotalModel();

    var totalsCounter = 1;

    var totalStr = string.Format(totalTemplate, totalsCounter);

    for (var row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
    {
        // target the first column
        string title = xlWorksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text;

        // if the first column is not TOTAL then continue
        if (title?.Equals(totalStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
            continue;

        // try convert values to the model.
        model.Tatoes20 += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 3);
        model.Bags42 += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 4);
        model.Tatoes14 += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 5);
        model.Tatoes28 += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 6);
        model.BagsA1 += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 7);
        model.Bags2Q += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 8);
        model.Bags2K += GetInt(xlWorksheet.Cells, row, 9);

        //add the next totals
        totalsCounter++;
        totalStr = string.Format(totalTemplate, totalsCounter); ;
    }
```

the `GetInt` method :

```
private static int GetInt(Excel.Range range, int row, int column)
{
    return int.TryParse(range?.Cells[row, column]?.Text, out int result) ? result : 0;
}
```